# Android Application - On Screen Keyboard Input Method

Tags: android, input, keyboard

I am trying to build an on screen keyboard, for a simple counter application, that adds some points for 2 diffeent teams in 2 columns.

[image]

The design thing is pretty simple, but it seems hard for me to programm the buttons, in order to insert numbers properly.

I have added all the necesery OnClickListeners and used for example this code for number 1

```
editText1.setText("1");
```

But, when i try to press the 1 button multiple times, it doesn't type 111 etc. It keeps replacing the last number that was inputed. So if i press 1 and then 2, it just replaces 1 with 2.

Any idea on how this can work please? :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

setText sets the text.  It doesn't append the text.  If you want to append, use `editText1.setText(editText1.getText()+"1");`